# php code of troubling getting multiple value

Tags: php, mysql

I have codes that should be getting value from mysql database, I can get only one value but I have while loop so it can get value and output data separated with comma. But I only get one value and cannot get multiple value. the result should be like this,  // End main PHP block. Data looks like this: [ [123456789, 20.9],[1234654321, 22.1] ]   here is the code:

```
<?php
// connect to MySQL
mysql_connect('localhost','','') or die("Can't connect that way!");
@mysql_select_db('temperature1') or die("Unable to select a database called 'temperature'");
if(ISSET($_GET['t']) && (is_numeric($_GET['t']))  ){
  // message from the Arduino
  $temp = $_GET['t'];

  $qry = "INSERT INTO tempArray(timing,temp) VALUES(".time().",'$temp')";
  echo $qry;
  mysql_query($qry);
  mysql_close();
  exit('200');
}
// no temp reading has been passed, lets show the chart.

$daysec = 60*60*24; //86,400
$daynow = time();
if(!$_GET['d'] || !is_numeric($_GET['d'])){
  $dayoffset = 1;
} else {
  $dayoffset = $_GET['d'];
}
$dlimit = $daynow-($daysec*$dayoffset);

$qryd = "SELECT id, timing, temp FROM tempArray WHERE timing>='$dlimit' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1008";

// 1008 is a weeks worth of data,
// assuming 10 min intervals
$r = mysql_query($qryd);

$count = mysql_num_rows($r);

$i=0;


$r = mysql_query($qryd);
$count = mysql_num_rows($r);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $tid=$row['id'];
  $dt = ($row['timing']+36000)*1000;
  $te = $row['temp'];

  if($te>$maxtemp) $maxtemp=$te; // so the graph doesnt run along the top
  if($te<$mintemp) $mintemp=$te; // or bottom of the axis
  $return="[$dt, $te]";
  echo $return; //here I get all values [1385435831000, 21][1385435862000, 23][1385435892000, 22][1385435923000, 25][1385435923000, 22]
  $i++;
  if($i<$count) $return= ","; echo $return; // if there is more data, add a ','    however, it return me ,,,[1385435923000, 22] 
  $latest = "$dt|$te"; // this will get filled up with each one
}
mysql_close();
// convert $latest to actual date - easier to do it here than in javascript (which I loathe)
$latest = explode('|',$latest);
$latest[0] = date('g:ia, j.m.Y',(($latest[0])/1000)-36000);


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just assigning $return to the values from the last row your while loop grabbed instead of concatenating it.  Try this

```
$return = "[";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $tid=$row['id'];
  $dt = ($row['timing']+36000)*1000;
  $te = $row['temp'];

 if($te>$maxtemp) $maxtemp=$te; // so the graph doesnt run along the top
 if($te<$mintemp) $mintemp=$te; // or bottom of the axis
 $return.="[$dt, $te]";
 $i++;
 if($i<$count) $return .= ", ";// if there is more data, add a ','
 $latest = "$dt|$te"; // this will get filled up with each one
}
$return .= "]";
```

Comment: it return me ] from my webpage

Comment: I got the value at $return="[$dt,$te]"; but I want to add comma between them so that it display like value1,value2,value3...

Comment: If you only got ] back then it still sounds like you're not concatenating.  notice the **.=**'s are you using that or **=**

Comment: I got it .. I just put another comma and then it works fine to me $return="[$dt, $te],"

Comment: You also added an echo at each step of the loop, which works fine but one echo at the end of the loop would have better performance.

Comment: thanks.  I am wondering how to add another channel two temperature value into this code.. do I need to do another while loop code ? I want to display two different line on my webpage...please help

Comment: Not quite sure that I understand what you are asking.  Are you trying to get a reference to these temperatures so you can use them at another time or are you trying to output another set of temperatures along with these?

Comment: I am trying to output another set of temperature along with these. but I want to output the first column temp first and then second column , and then third column. I do not want to display the row1, row2, and then row3. in my database, I have three coloumn of different temperature. Is that possible to code that ? thanks

Comment: I think I follow you, and yes.  You could do 3 loops like the one you've just done.  But a better solution would be to write the sql query to include all three columns for each row and concatenate each column together and then after the loop echo each column.